# DataTables sorting for category name column doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Here is HTML code

```
 <table id="datatable-language" class="table table-hover datatable-highlight">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>image</th>
                            <th>category_name</th>
                            <th>status</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
```

Here is the JS code inside Datatable

```
columns: [
                    {
                        title: `<input type="checkbox" class="styled" onchange='toggleSelectAll(this);'>`,
                        orderable: false,
                        data: "category_id",
                        width: "50px"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "image",
                        render: function (data, type, row) {
                            return `<img src="${row['image']}" height="50px">`;
                        },
                        width: "100px"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "name",
                        ordering: true,
                        render: function (data, type, row) {
                            return `<a href="{{ link('catalog/category/update?category_id=') }}${row['category_id']}">${row['name']}</a>`;
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: "cstatus",
                        width: "30px"
                    },
                    {
                        width: "30px",
                        data: "category_id"
                    },
                    {
                        width: "10px",
                        data: "category_id"
                    },
                ],
columnDefs: [
                    {
                        targets: 1,
                        orderable: true
                    },
                    {
                        targets: 2,
                        orderable: true
                    },
                    {
                        orderable: false,
                        className: 'select-checkbox',
                        targets: 0
                    },
                    {
                        targets: 3,
                        render: function (data, type, row) {
                            var status = (data == "1" ? 'checked="checked"' : '');
                            return statusSwitch(row.category_id, status);
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        targets: 4,
                        orderable: false,
                        selectable: false,
                        visible: true,
                        render: function (data, type, row) {
                            return `<a data-popup="tooltip" title="${locales['text_preview']}" target="_blank" href="{{ linkfront('product/category', 'path=') }}${row['category_id']}" class='text-default'><i class='fa fa-eye fa-lg valign-middle'></i></a>`;
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        targets: 5,
                        orderable: false,
                        render: function (data, type, row) {
                            return `<ul class="icons-list pull-right">
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                            <i class="icon-menu9"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                            <li><a href='{{ link('catalog/category/update') }}?category_id=${row['category_id']}'><i class='icon-pencil7'></i> ${locales['button_edit']}</a></li>
                                            <li><a onclick="removeItem(${row['category_id']})"><i class='icon-trash'></i> ${locales['button_delete']}</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            `;
                        }
                    }
                ]
```

As you see, I make the orderable attr to true and the category_name still not working. Is there's a missing property of config?!
so what is the problem? the rest of the code doesn't make sense at all. I attached the snippets that make the table configurations

Answer (score 0):

```
 {
  data: "name",
  ordering: true,
  render: function (data, type, row) {
    return `<a href="{{ link('catalog/category/update?category_id=') }}${row['category_id']}">${row['name']}</a>;
  }
```

you write this
change `data:"name"` to `data:"category_name"`

and also return

```
<a href="{{ link('catalog/category/update?category_id=') }}${row['category_id']}">${row['name']}</a>;
```

here change name to category_name

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `columns.render` docs > https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render, especially the type param.

Your problem is that DT will sort the columns rendered markup, not the `name` value itself. So pass back the `name` value for sorting, markup for everything else:

```
render: function (data, type, row) {
    return type == 'sort'
      ? row['name']
      : `<a href="{{ link('catalog/category/update?category_id=') }}${row['category_id']}">${row['name']}</a>;
 }
```